# Select class control-group where none of its children are span.error

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

I am working with twitter bootstrap and the jquery validate plugin

I have a form row that looks like:

```
<div class="form_row" >
<div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label" for="input01">home phone</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input type="number" class="span4" class="input-xlarge" id="home_phone" name="home_phone" value="<?php echo $this->property->home_phone ?>" rel="popover" data-content="Re-enter your home phone." data-original-title="homephone" >
    <input type="number" class="span4" class="input-xlarge" id="cell_phone" name="cell_phone" value="<?php echo $this->property->cell_phone ?>"  rel="popover" data-content="Re-enter your cell_phone." data-original-title="cell_phone" >
  </div>
```

after validation, when I look at it in firebug, the inputs with errors are followed by span.error.I would like to select class control-group where none of its children are span.error. I would appreciate any help.

Thanks  , Bill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
$('.control-group').not($('.control-group span.error').closest('.control-group')).
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/Dhe4j/

In the jsfiddle example we select all the `.control-group` which don't have nested `span.error` and make them red.

Comment: Hi Zerkms, I noticed that it is still picking up child input classes with span.error's after them. after closer inspection I realized that these are generated classes, presumably added by the jquery validate plugin. I am going to accept your answer and try to figure out how to remove the generated error classes when the actual visible error spans are gone. Thanks for your help. - Bill