# trying to use if and find in jquery to generate a boolean expression

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

I am working with twitter bootstrap and the jquery validate plugin

I have a several form rows that look like:

```
<div class="form_row" >
<div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label" for="input01">home phone</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input type="number" class="span4" class="input-xlarge" id="home_phone" name="home_phone" value="<?php echo $this->property->home_phone ?>" rel="popover" data-content="Re-enter your home phone." data-original-title="homephone" >
    <input type="number" class="span4" class="input-xlarge" id="cell_phone" name="cell_phone" value="<?php echo $this->property->cell_phone ?>"  rel="popover" data-content="Re-enter your cell_phone." data-original-title="cell_phone" >
  </div>
```

after validation, when I look at it in firebug, the inputs with errors are followed by span.error.I would like to select class control-group divs where at least 1 of each divs children are span.error ( I believe these are tacked on by jquery validate), and then add the error class and remove success classes from the control group divs that fail validation. Does the following look like it would work? II think it should but the correct classes do not seem to be added and subtracted.

```
if ( $('div.control-group').find('span.error').length) {$(this).addClass('error').removeClass('success');}
```

Thanks  , Bill

Comment: How is it different from http://stackoverflow.com/q/12048278/251311 ?

Comment: I was trying to construct a similar query using a boolean approach. My problem is that I have been testing queries using the firebug command line. But when I enter my string above, instead of outputting an array with relevant elements, it outputs:  [Window /bootstrap1/] ( bootstrap1 being the name of my app. I am not sure how to test my query, with that output. Can someone explain the output, and/or recommend an alternate way to test in this situation?  Thank you - Bill